# Tunable phase delay for RF modulation

Tags: electrical-engineering, optics, rf-electronics, electronics

I've been trying to understand if there's a way to create two RF signals at the same frequency with a fixed, tunable phase delay. The goal is for one to trigger an RF-modulated laser and the other an electronic device, with the laser used to measure a property of the device. By varying the phase difference between the signals I could measure this property with time resolution, similar to [pump-probe spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pump%E2%80%93probe_microscopy). The technique in use there mainly uses an optical pump and an optical probe, meaning the time difference between the pulses can be varied by an optical delay stage, but in this application the "pump" pulse is electrical, and the probe is optical, so a different solution is needed.
I don't have access to an expensive function generator which I imagine could help with this, so I was hoping to have some advice on whether this is plausible, and whether it can be achieved with standard electronics.